# Can I determine the class load strategy of the same class by nesting modules?

Tags: java, maven

Does the **way of building with modules influence** which java class with the same name is used? We use 'maven' as a build tool with Intelli-J.

So, this is a different question then many similar questions. I know about the class loader and the JAR's loaded in sequence.

**Module 1**: has a.b.ClassWithSameName.class

**Module 2**: has a.b.ClassWithSameName.class

**Module 3**: includes (via a maven dependency) module 1 and has 1 class Module3ClassName.class that is using the a.b.ClassWithSameName.class of module 1

**Module 4**: includes (via a maven dependency) module 2 and has 1 class Module4ClassName.class that is using the a.b.ClassWithSameName.class of module 2

**Module 5**: includes (via a maven dependency) module 3 and module 4.

When I use Module3ClassName.class and Module4ClassName.class will they use the right versions of the a.b.ClassWithSameName.class?

**If not**, what can I do to have the right a.b.ClassWithSameName.classes called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Influencing the order of classes cannot be done. The first class on the class path with the specific name is used.

This what I read so far. If you have a better answer, please let me know. I will remove this post.